# Xquery to return an object and its associated reference

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an XML file like this (but with many drug and partner entries):

```
<drugs>
  <drug>
    <name>abc</name>
    <target partner="100" />
  </drug>
  <partner id="100">
    <name>gene</name>
  </partner>
</drugs>
```

I want to pull out the drug and target.  You can see that the two are related to each other by the partner id.  Is there a way to get the drug name and partner gene name in a single xquery statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but assuming you want to get all associations from a larger  set of XML data:

```
for $d in $drugs/drug
let $partner := $drugs/partner[@id = $d/target/@partner]
return
  element assoc {
    attribute drug-name { $d/name },
    attribute partner-name { $partner/name }
  }
```

If there could be multiple partners per drug, then you would want to use elements for partner instead of an attribute in the output.